# Convert multitple columns to datetime

Tags: sql-server

How can I convert multitple columns to datetime in MsSQL?

I have 3 columns that is all in varchar data type. and the month column contains the full name of the month(January).
this is my table.

```
date  month      Year
01    January    2013
02    February   2014
03    March      2015
```

Comment: Post the exact format of your value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

If you have saved all fields with varchar type

```
SELECT convert(datetime, date + ' ' + substring(month, 1, 3) + ' ' + year, 106)
from yourtable
```

If date and year are int you can write:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, convert(varchar, date) + ' ' +
substring(month, 1, 3) + ' ' + convert(varchar, year), 106)
from yourtable
```

For further info see [here](http://linesofcode.net/snippets/45)

Answer (score 0):

Use Concat all the columns and use `Convert` function to convert to date. Try this.

```
select convert(date,[date]+' '+[month]+' '+[year])
from yourtable
```

Or If you are using `sql server 2012+` use `DATEFROMPARTS` function

```
select DATEFROMPARTS('2013',
                      case [month] when 'January' then 1 
                              when 'Feb' then 2 
                              ....,
                      ,'01')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare 
@an varchar(100) = '01',
@luna varchar(100) = 'January',
@zi varchar(100) = '2013'


SELECT CONVERT(datetime,@zi+' '+SUBSTRING(@luna,1,3)+' '+@an,106)
```

The 106 format is DD-MMM-YYYY. If youare positive all the Month values are in english.

See this example :

```
print CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate the values and convert the varchar value to a date like so:

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7557d/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE DateTable
    ([date] varchar(2), [month] varchar(8), [Year] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO DateTable
    ([date], [month], [Year])
VALUES
    ('01', 'January', '2013'),
    ('02', 'February', '2014'),
    ('03', 'March', '2015')
;
```

**Query to concatenate and Convert values**:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, d.[date] + d.[month] + d.[year]) AS FormattedDate 
FROM DateTable d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7557d/1/0)**:

```
| FormattedDate |
|---------------|
| 2013-01-01    |
| 2014-02-02    |
| 2015-03-03    |
```